# error with oci_fetch_array, can retrieve data from oracle by php

Tags: php, oracle

i can retrieve data from oracle db by php when i try do loop to get data it give me error

undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\test.php on line 15

here is my code

```
<?php
$username = "kemo";
$password = "kemoacer77";
$server = "localhost/XE";
$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $server);
if(!$conn){
die("connect error".oci_error());
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT id, username FROM users');
oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH))) {
    // Use the uppercase column names for the associative array indices
    echo  $row['id'] ;
    echo $row['username'];
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [**`oci_fetch_array()`**](http://www.php.net/oci_fetch_array) says :

> Oracle's default, **non-case sensitive
>   column names will have uppercase
>   associative indices in the result
>   array**. Case-sensitive column names
>   will have array indices using the
>   exact column case. 
> Use
>   `var_dump()` on the result array to
>   verify the appropriate case to use for
>   each query.

And the comment in your code also says :

```
// Use the uppercase column names for the associative array indices
```

So, **why are you using lowercase column names ?**

This is your code :

```
echo  $row['id'] ;
echo $row['username'];
```

According to the comment in your code, and the note in the manual, should you not use uppercase, like this :

```
echo  $row['ID'] ;
echo $row['USERNAME'];
```

And, if this still doesn't work, just do as said in the manual : use [**`var_dump()`**](http://www.php.net/var_dump) in your loop, to see how your data looks like :

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH))) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: wow all right now when change username, id to capital character USERNAME, ID its run good

Comment: but how i can check if query have error in php + mysql i use this way `if(!$query){die(mysql_error())} ` how can do it with oracle

Comment: It seems `oci_execute()` returns false on failure : http://www.php.net/oci_execute

Comment: Well, if there is an error in the SQL query, it fails -- and that function will return false, I suppose *(just use some invalid SQL Query, and you'll know :-) )*

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used NVL

The Oracle/PLSQL NVL function lets you substitute a value when a null value is encountered

NVL( string1, replace_with )

SELECT NVL(commission, 0) FROM sales;

Output:

123
223
323

423

answer would be like
123
223
323
0
423